# How to get rid of the extra white space caused by hidden elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this search bar that searches through the texts of buttons to filter out options. Basically, it's a button filter. However, whenever it filters the buttons are still in their original position which leaves a bunch of white space everywhere.

This is the HTML of the search bar:

```
<div id=searchBar>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Catalog"> 
<button type="submit" id="searchButton">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

and the jQuery/JavaScript of the search bar:

```
$("#search").on("input", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById('searchButton').onclick = function(){
    $("#page button").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This code looks strange to me... On `input` in the seach bar, you are declaring a `click` handler for `#searchButton`... Now you say it's executing... It probably executes the previous declared one. That, from start, does not look good. -- About white spaces, it is certainly due to line returns in your markup. Try having the whole button (from`<button>` to `</button>` on one single line. **or** wrap it witth a `div` and toggle the div instead of the button.

Comment: The whitespace is caused by the hidden buttons. I have an area that has over 50 buttons and when you search for a specific button it only shows buttons with that text. However, if the button was positioned on the end of the list, it stays there rather than appearing at the top. I want the hidden buttons to no longer take up space.

Comment: Is there any `<br>` after each of your button? ;)

Comment: Yes, there's a <br> between each. Should I take them out?

Comment: You should toggle them too...

Comment: Thank you so much. I just removed the <br> and edited the div's css and it works perfectly.

Comment: ;) Excellent. Happy coding!